# Sending message to server using python SocketIO

Tags: python-2.7, socket.io

I have a situation where I have a python client try to send a message to a server using SocketIO. I'm using sock.emit to send a json message as shown below

```
    sock = SocketIO(url, None, ...)
    message = {'ob': 'house',
               'ids': ['54fjadb70f9756','39f1ax451f6567']}
    self.sock.emit(message)
```

server expects the follow:

```
     {"ob":"house","ids":['54fjadb70f9756','39f1ax451f6567']}
```

the server is current receive the following message:

```
    {"args": [], "name": "{\"ids\": [\"54fjadb70f9756\", \"39f1ax451f6567\"], \"ob\": \"house\"}"}
```

then complains about an invalid message.

How would I send the message so that the server receives it as expected i.e which the original message structure I specified? it seems emit is changing the structure of the message when I send it, is it possible to override and change emit to that it retain the original message structure? is so how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Socket.io `.emit()` takes two arguments.  The first argument is a message name which should be a plain string.  The second argument is optional and can be data which will be JSON encoded data.

So, you are trying to send your data as the message name.  That will not work.  You need to create a message name and send the data as the argument for that message name.

```
sock = SocketIO(url, None, ...)
message = {'ob': 'house',
           'ids': ['54fjadb70f9756','39f1ax451f6567']}
sock.emit("someMessageName", message)
```

Then, on the server, you need to have a listener for that specific message name and then you can receive the data when that message listener is invoked.